# Using Keras' TensorBoard callback with `write_images=True`: save images less often

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I would like to fix issues regarding when the images are saved when using the tensorboard callback with `write_images=True`: 
https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard

Could it be possible to plot a convnet's weights only at the end of the training with TensorBoard this way?

Right now it seems like if TensorBoard wanted to save the images at every epochs, and the file sizes are getting really huge. I get something like 5 GB per epoch on the MNIST dataset and [this convolutional neural network](https://github.com/Vooban/Hyperopt-Keras-CNN-CIFAR-100) convnet) just to save those `write_images=True`.

Right now the images are saved at a frequency of `histogram_freq=1` since I call it with the value of 1. But I want my histograms to be saved at every epoch or so rather than only at the end.

Would using a second TensorBoard callback with a different frequency work, and if so, how?

Also, I would like to discard the biases of the convolutions in this callback or to transpose them sideways, because those `63px x 1px` images are showing up enlarged 342 times in a way that they span 10 screens in height. And I am not sure how to interpret the convolutional kernels, they should be 3D considering the depth of the channels, not only monochrome 2D (I use the CIFAR-10 dataset).

Comment: I see multiple questions in what you are asking. Could you show the code you are using to perform that saving? Using a different `histogram_freq`, say 2, will give you half as much data, as you will save every 2 epochs. It also depends on the training you give it, as more training means more epochs therefore more data to save. Try with different frequencies and you will see the change, if it works let me know to write an answer (im an not currently on pc)

Comment: I have a different question here based on the same code, in which it is possible to see more code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178982/how-to-use-embeddings-in-the-tensorboard-callback-of-keras

Comment: Ok, do try using a frequency with value greater than 1 and let me know if it reduces your output size.

Comment: With half the frequency, the final folder size is half the size. So ti really does 5+ GB of data per epoch. If I run 2 epochs, I would get nearly 10 GB with a frequency of 1, and nearly 5 GB with a frequency of 2. So I would need a way to save histograms often and weight images less often. And there is still the problem that the weight images seems broken in the "images" tab in TensorBoard.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I found another alternative, how are you using the parameter `embeddings_freq`?